# How to allow for new property in an Interface that has nested array

Tags: angular, typescript, types, rxjs

I have an interface in that interface there is a property called `data` which is an array.
So looks something like this:

```
type Data = { prop1: string; prop2: string }[]; 

interface MyInterface {
  prop1: string;
  data: Data;
}
```

Now I have an RxJS stream,

In that stream, the interface is `MyInterface`.

So now I want to display something slightly different in the data property.
So what I did was Extend add a new value

```
type DataExtended = Data & {
  newValue: string
}
```

Add that new type to an extended interface

```
interface MyInterfaceExtended extends MyInterface {
  data: DataExtended
}
```

Now in the controller, I call a service that has an HTTP service that has `MyInterface` as the expected result. But I need to change that data structure, so I have the following:

```
var myData$ = Observable<MyInterfaceExtended>;

constructor(private myService:myservice){
  this.myData$ = this.myService.get().pipe((map(value)) => {
      foreach(value.data,  (data) =>{
        data.newValue = 'new';
      })
      return value
  })
}
```

But I keep getting the error that says:

> 'newValue' does not exist on type {etc}

Why would that be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assumption:**

Assume that the `this.myService.get()` returns `Observable<MyInterface>`.

There is an issue with the `DataExtended` type, as you combine the `Data` which is an array of `{ prop1: string; prop2: string }` type with an object `{ newValue: string }`.

The correct type should be:

```
type DataExtended = Data &
  {
    newValue: string;
  }[];
```

for existing types.

Or you should define the `Data` as a single object rather than an array type.

**New types:**

```
type Data = { prop1: string; prop2: string };

interface MyInterface {
  prop1: string;
  data: Data[];
}

type DataExtended = Data &
  {
    newValue: string;
  };

interface MyInterfaceExtended extends MyInterface {
  data: DataExtended[];
}
```

---

For converting the data with the `map` RxJS operator, you can achieve with:

**Solution 1 with existing types:**

```
this.myData$ = this.myService.get()
  .pipe(
    map((response: any) => {
      let newResponse: MyInterfaceExtended = response;

      newResponse.data = newResponse.data.map((x) => ({
        ...x,
        newValue: 'new',
      }));

      return newResponse;
    })
  );
```

**Solution 2 with the new types:**

```
this.myData$ = this.myService.get()
  .pipe(
    map(
      (response: any) =>
        ({
          data: response.data.map(
            (x: Data) =>
              ({
                ...x,
                newValue: 'new',
              } as DataExtended)
          ),
        } as MyInterfaceExtended)
    )
  );
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-4xmrnu?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Answer (score 1):

#### This is how to create generic interfaces.

```js
interface BaseUserDetails<TID = number> {
  id: TID;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

interface UserWithContacts extends BaseUserDetails<number> {
  phone: string;
}

interface User<TUserDetail> {
  details: TUserDetail;
}

const baseUser: User<BaseUserDetails> = {
  details: {
    id: 1,
    firstName: 'first name',
    lastName: 'last name',
  },
};

const userWithContact: User<UserWithContacts> = {
  details: {
    id: 1,
    firstName: 'first name',
    lastName: 'last name',
    phone: '--- --- -- --',
  },
};
```

#### Another Example

```
interface BaseEntity<ID> {
  id: ID;
}

interface SelectIDField<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T> {
  idField: K;
}

interface UserEntity
  extends BaseEntity<number>,
    SelectIDField<UserEntity, 'uuid' | 'username'> {
  uuid: string;
  username: string;
  password: string;
}
```